# Why does it take so long for my json to load?

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

I'm building an app that shows users the closest gyms, then gives them directions.  I'm using Google Places Web API.  The app runs as it's supposed to, except that it takes 24 seconds to download the json.  Why is this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
int REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;
DownloadTask task;
Double lat;
Double lng;
ArrayList<String> gymName;
ArrayList<String> gymLat;
ArrayList<String> gymLng;


ListView gymNameList;
ArrayAdapter<String> gymNameAdapter;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    task = new DownloadTask();
    gymLat = new ArrayList<>();
    gymLng = new ArrayList<>();
    gymName = new ArrayList<>();
    gymNameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    gymNameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,gymName);
    gymNameList.setAdapter(gymNameAdapter);


gymNameList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + gymLat.get(position) + "," + gymLng.get(position));
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
});



    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null){



        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();

        Log.e("Location info: Lat", lat.toString());
        Log.e("Location info: Lng", lng.toString());
    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "damn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    task.execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + String.valueOf(lat) + "," + String.valueOf(lng) + "&radius=50000&type=gym&&key=AIzaSyCoOcFh0aduUuDMqw6TlUk5sjOpZjkKBAg");

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Double lat = location.getLatitude();
    Double lng = location.getLongitude();

    Log.i("Location info: Lat", lat.toString());
    Log.i("Location info: Lng", lng.toString());

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}


public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;


        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String weatherContent = jsonObject.getString("results");

            Log.i("gymresults", weatherContent);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(weatherContent);



            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){


                JSONObject jsonPart = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject jsonLocation = jsonPart.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
               String gymNName = jsonPart.getString("name");
                gymName.add(gymNName);
                gymNameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                String latLong = jsonPart.getString("geometry");
                String lat = jsonLocation.getString("lat");
                String lng = jsonLocation.getString("lng");

                Log.i("frick", lat);
                Log.i("frack", lng);

                gymLat.add(lat);
                gymLng.add(lng);

                Log.i("gymname", gymNName);
                Log.i("gymlocation", latLong);


            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you timing the start and stop of the download?

Comment: When the app starts is the beginning and when the listview is populated is the end

Comment: I timed that and it takes 24 seconds

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  Benchmarking code doesn't involve using a stopwatch.  You need to put log statements at the various phases and use that to understand what exactly is taking a long time.